# How to register one touch event for each criteria (Right and Left of screen)

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I would like to be able to check if the user is touching the screen on the right or left half however cant seem to make it work, I will post the relevant code below, hopefully I'm on the right tracks(ish)!

**Edit**
I think the real problem is reading the information as it happens. For example I don't know how to read taps on the right side of the screen while the user is still holding on the left side of the screen. I assume I am getting caught up in conditional statements.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    int fingers = motionEvent.getPointerCount(); //How many items should be in array

    ArrayList<Float> fingersArray = new ArrayList<>(); //Declares ArrayList of floats for each finger on the screen

    for (int countUp = 0; countUp < fingers; countUp++) {

        fingersArray.add(motionEvent.getX(countUp));
        if (fingersArray.get(countUp) < (screenX/2)) {
            playerDirection = DIRECTION_UP;
            break;
        } else {
            playerDirection = DIRECTION_DOWN;
        }
        if (fingersArray.get(countUp) > (screenX/2) && motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            bullets.add(new Bullet(getContext(), player.getX(), player.getY()));
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Currently this code doesn't let the user move and shoot at the same time and when I take my finger off the left side of the screen the user continues moving up when it should move back down.

**Edit**

Upon review of Jelic98's answer I have the following and it almost works however I cannot hold my finger on the left hand of the screen (to move the player up) and tap the right side (to shoot). It will only move the player up and not shoot. Current code is as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    ArrayList<Float> positions = new ArrayList<>();

    // if event.getPointerCount().size() is 0 then no finger is pressed
    for(int fingerIndex = 0; fingerIndex < event.getPointerCount(); fingerIndex++) {

        float x = event.getX(fingerIndex);

        switch(action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // first finger is pressed
                if (x<(screenX/2)){
                    player.setMoveUp(true);
                } else {
                    bullets.add(new Bullet(getContext(), player.getX(), player.getY()));
                }
                    break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (player.getMoveUp()){
                    player.setMoveUp(false);
                }
                // last finger is released
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                // finger that is or first is pressed
                // there is at least 1 finger pressed before this moment
                bullets.add(new Bullet(getContext(), player.getX(), player.getY()));
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                // finger that is or last is released
                // there is at least 1 finger pressed before this moment
                if (player.getMoveUp() && event.getPointerCount() < 1){
                    player.setMoveUp(false);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should remove elements from fingersArray when ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL are detected and then unset playerDirection.

Comment: But If I do this will I be able to click both the right and the left side of the screen at the same time and register different events (The left side of the screen decides if the user is moving up or down the screen and the right side decides if the user should be shooting or not)

Comment: Take a look at this https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html

Comment: Thank you for the information, it's helpful to understand more about how it works. I guess the real problem is reading the information as it happens. For example I don't know how to read taps on the right side of the screen while the user is still holding on the left side of the screen. I assume I am getting caught up in conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

I've commented your code.

```
for(int countUp = 0; countUp < fingers; countUp++) {
        fingersArray.add(motionEvent.getX(countUp));

        // here you are using left half of the screen to move up
        // and right half of the screen to move down
        if(fingersArray.get(countUp) < (screenX / 2)) {
            playerDirection = DIRECTION_UP;
            break;
        }else {
            playerDirection = DIRECTION_DOWN;
        }

        // this is the second place where are you using right half
        // but now it's for shooting so if user taps on right half
        // of the screen player moves down and also shoots!!
        if(fingersArray.get(countUp) > (screenX / 2) 
                && motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            bullets.add(new Bullet(getContext(), player.getX(), player.getY()));
        }
}
```

This is my version that explains handling multiple touches, but you should fill your logic in.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        ArrayList<Float> positions = new ArrayList<>();

        switch(action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // first finger is pressed
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // last finger is released
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                // finger that is or first is pressed
                // there is at least 1 finger pressed before this moment
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                // finger that is or last is released
                // there is at least 1 finger pressed before this moment
                break;
        }

        // if event.getPointerCount().size() is 0 then no finger is pressed
        for(int fingerIndex = 0; fingerIndex < event.getPointerCount(); fingerIndex++) {
            // if fingerIndex is 0 then only 1 finger is pressed
            // if fingerIndex is 1 then there are 2 fingers are pressed, etc.

            int id = event.getPointerId(fingerIndex);

            float x = event.getX(fingerIndex);
            float y = event.getY(fingerIndex);
        }

        return true;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have updated my post to include what I currently have and how it works. Still facing some problems with how it works.